# Cannot figure out negative lookahead with Parsec

Tags: haskell, parsec, regex-lookarounds

I'm a beginner with Haskell, so it might be very obvious what I'm doing wrong...

While trying to parse `"1:1,2, 2:18, 3:100"` into `[(1,1), (1,2), (2,18), (3,100)]` I got stuck on a lookahead.

To know if a number is a verse number it should look ahead for a colon, because then it is a chapter number instead.

The problem lies in the last function `verseNr`, it should parse+consume the number if not followed by a colon, otherwise fail without consuming anything (leaving the number to be parsed as a chapter number by `refGroupByChapter`).

Except for this issue it seems to work nicely :)

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec

main = do
  case (parse refString "(unknown)" "1:1,2, 2:18, 3:100") of
    Left  e -> do putStr "parse error at "; print e
    Right x -> print x  -- expecting: [(1,1), (1,2), (2,18), (3,100)]

refString :: GenParser Char st [(Int, Int)]
refString = do
  refGroups <- many refGroupByChapter
  eof
  return $ concat $ map flatten refGroups
  where flatten (_, [])   = []
        flatten (c, v:vs) = (c, v):(flatten (c, vs))

refGroupByChapter :: GenParser Char st (Int, [Int])
refGroupByChapter = do
  chapterNum <- many digit
  char ':'
  verseNums <- verseNrs
  return ((read chapterNum :: Int), verseNums)

verseNrs :: GenParser Char st [Int]
verseNrs = do
  first <- verseNr
  remaining <- remainingVerseNrs
  return (first:remaining)
  where
    remainingVerseNrs = do  -- allow for spaces around the commas
      (spaces >> oneOf "," >> spaces >> verseNrs) <|> (return [])
    verseNr = try $ do
      n <- many1 digit
      notFollowedBy $ char ':'  -- if followed by a ':' it's a chapter number
      return (read n :: Int)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick for your particular problem would be to use the `sepBy` family of functions. You're parsing lists of numbers separated by commas, which is exactly what `sepBy` is for. A list of verses has the following properties: there has to be at least one verse number and there is a trailing comma. Combining the two, we realize we need the `sepEndBy1` function. These functions are usually written in an infix position, so your code would look something like this:

```
verseNrs = verseNr `sepEndBy1` (spaces >> char ',' >> spaces)
```

I don't think you need to change anything else to get the code to work.

A couple of other minor style notes: you have some unnecessary parentheses. This isn't important, it just annoys me personally. E.g. in `case ... of` you do *not* need parens around the `...` bit. Also, you do not need the type signature when you use `read`--the compiler can infer the type. That is, since `verseNrs` returns `[Int]`, it's completely clear both to the compiler and to me that `read n` produces an `Int`. There is no need to say it explicitly.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. It worked beautifully, and your style remarks also found their way into my code.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems. First, the function `verseNr` may not always succeed on parsing a number, as the number might be followed by a `:`. While the`verseNrs` function always assumes that `verseNr` succeeds on parsing a digit by pattern matching against it as `first`. Second, the function `verseNrs` does not handle the case of the last digit in the string, which is not followed by a `,`.

I believe Tikhon's suggestion is the best. However, if you insist on implementing it manually, here is how I would do it.

```
import Control.Monad (void)
import Control.Applicative ((<*))

verseNrs :: GenParser Char st [Int]
verseNrs = do
    first <- fmap Just (try (many1 digit
                          <* spaces
                          <* (eof <|> void (char ','))
                          <* spaces))
             <|> return Nothing
    case first of
      Just first -> fmap (read first:) verseNrs
      Nothing    -> return []
```

The rest of the code is the same.